# Почему указывает на ошибку в gradle?

Tags: java, android, opencv

Такая проблема когда я создал новый проект и импортировал модуль OpenCV (все как сказано в этом [видео](https://goo.gl/bLE7Gs)), то все заработало, но как только я попробовал проделать тоже самое с уже существующим проектом, то у меня вывалилась какае то ошибка которая не понятно, что означает(прикрепил скриншот)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Какой плагин проект не может найти? и почему когда я в новом проекте это сделал это работает, а когда я тоже самое делаю в существующем прокете, то вот такая ошибка... Как это починить?

gradle файлы

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
}
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
jcenter()
}

dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:23.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
compile files('libs/svgandroid.jar')
compile files('libs/svg-android.jar')
compile files('libs/guava-16.0.1.jar')
}

// The sample build uses multiple directories to
// keep boilerplate and common code separate from
// the main sample code.
List<String> dirs = [
'main',     // main sample code; look here for the interesting stuff.
'common',   // components that are reused by multiple samples
'template'] // boilerplate code that is generated by the sample  template process

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 22
    targetSdkVersion 23
}

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        dirs.each { dir ->
            java.srcDirs "src/${dir}/java"
            res.srcDirs "src/${dir}/res"
        }
    }
    androidTest.setRoot('tests')
    androidTest.java.srcDirs = ['tests/src']

}
}
```

Comment: Покажите ваши gradle- файлы

Comment: добавил файл по приложению

Comment: ошибку напишите текстом, а не скриншотом.

Comment: а, что от этого поменяется? На скриншоте плохо видно?

Comment: Так почему ошибку показывает? Как сделать так, чтоб работало?

Comment: Да вроде как `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'` нужно опустить ниже `repositories {
jcenter()
}`